# Truffle tries deploy from unknown account

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, infura, truffle-deployment

I am trying to deploy a contract to Ropsten using Infura with the config file `truffle.js` below. The deploy fails because the account listed in the error message has insufficient funds – however I do not recognise the account given. It does not appear in the top 15 accounts associated with my mnemonic (e.g. using MyEtherWallet). I am inserting my mnemonic in the format `word word word word`.

The actual account 0 associated with my mnemonic has ample Ether from the faucet.

What am I doing wrong?

`truffle.js`

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
var mnemonic = "<MNEMONIC>";
var infuraAPIKey = "<INFURA-PROJECT-SECRET>";
const infuraUrl = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/'+infuraAPIKey;

const NonceSubprovider = require("web3-provider-engine/subproviders/nonce-tracker"); 
const createInfuraProvider = (mnemonic, infuraUrl) => { 
  let provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, infuraUrl); 
  provider.engine.addProvider(new NonceSubprovider()); 
  return provider; 
}
module.exports = {
   networks: {
     development: {
       host: "localhost",
       port: 7545,
       network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    rinkeby: {
      host: "localhost",
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/"+infuraAPIKey, 0),
      port: 7545,
      network_id: 4,
      gas: 4712388
    },
    live: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8546,
      provider: createInfuraProvider(mnemonic, infuraUrl),
        network_id: 1,
        gas: 4712388
    }
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.4.24"
    }
  }
};
```

Error message:

```
1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" could not deploy due to insufficient funds
   * Account:  0xdBB63dca232c0deF386758eAC53A0B7Cc558217b
   * Balance:  0 wei
   * Message:  sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The upfront cost is: 9424776000000000 and the sender's account only has: 0
   * Try:
      + Using an adequately funded account
      + If you are using a local Geth node, verify that your node is synced.

    at /Users/technical/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-deployer/src/deployment.js:364:1
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Truffle v5.0.7 (core: 5.0.7)
Node v10.15.3
```

Answer (score 1):

**HDWalletProvider** and **MyEtherWallet**, They both are work differently so there is some alternative you can use:

> 1. Using Private keys:

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
//load single private key as string
var provider = new HDWalletProvider("3f841bf589fdf83a521e55d51afddc34fa65351161eead24f064855fc29c9580", "http://localhost:8545");

// Or, pass an array of private keys, and optionally use a certain subset of addresses
var privateKeys = [
  "3f841bf589fdf83a521e55d51afddc34fa65351161eead24f064855fc29c9580",
  "9549f39decea7b7504e15572b2c6a72766df0281cea22bd1a3bc87166b1ca290",
];
var provider = new HDWalletProvider(privateKeys, "http://localhost:8545", 0, 2); //start at address_index 0 and load both addresses
```

> 2. Update Migration File to Get Addresses:

```
module.exports = function(deployer,network,accounts) {   
console.log(accounts);  
deployer.deploy(Migrations); 
};
```

Comment: This still does not work. I changed your line `console.log(a)` to `console.log(accounts)` and it shows a different list of accounts each time. However, the Account listed by Truffle as the deploying account with no funds remains the same, and is unrelated to the private key. I am using MetaMask to extract the private key.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Either `When you go for  **console.log(accounts)** it will show all addresses that are generated so next time you know what address will be responsible for transaction and so you can fill that account with some ether.` 
Or `Instead of using **mnemonic** you can use private that can be extract from Metamask`

Comment: The trouble is, I don't have access to the addresses listed in the console. I have tried the mnemonic and private key approach, and the addresses that I see and fill with ether e.g. in Metamask, do not correspond with the addresses logged by Truffle.

Comment: What I did was send some ETH to address showed on `web3.eth.getAccounts()` from truffle console.